# Vaadin 14: How to add an upload action as GridMenuItem?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I tried:

```
var buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
var upload = new Upload(buffer);
upload.setDropAllowed(false);
upload.addSucceededListener(event -> {
    LOG.info("Upload succeeded '%s' (%s)", event.getFileName(), event.getMIMEType());
});

var menu = grid.addContextMenu();
menu.addItem(upload);
```

Result:

[image]

This looks really ugly and is also not exactly what a user expects. If the user selects the "Upload file" menu item, the file chooser should be shown.

Comment: I tried your code, the upload works without errors. Could you please provide enough code to reproduce the error?

Comment: @J11 I updated my question. Forget about the error. The main issue (not clear in the original post) is the styling of the Upload button within the GridContextMenu. Ideally it should look exactly the same as other GridMenuItem actions